# Howto tell if generated event is sent by it's own class

Tags: c#-4.0

Is there a way to tell if an event is raised in it's own caller. Essentially I have 1.N classes, all essentially the same, each run by a thread. I have an enum which differentiates the basic types. I have a delegate in the top level class, ExecutionState, which creates all the sub classes, (stores them in a collection). I have the following in each class. ExecutionState is the top level creator class which contains the delegate and the associated event as

```
    public void Subscribe(ExecutionState ExecState)
    {
        if (this.ExpressionInstance.IsMultiLine)
        {
            ExecState.MultiMatchEvent += new ExecutionState.MultiMatch(Signal);
        }
    }

    private void Signal(int ProcessorPosition)
    { 
    }

    private void SendEvent(ExecutionState.MultiMatch Match)
    {
        if ((Status & RuleState.HasEnd) == RuleState.HasEnd)
        {
            Match(CurrentProcessorNumber);
        }
    }
```

ExecutionState is the top level creator class which contains the delegate and the associated event as:

```
public delegate void MultiMatch(int ProcessorPosition);     
public event MultiMatch MultiMatchEvent;
```

When I call SendEvent, I assume an event will arrive at Signal, at its own class. Of course, Subscribe only needs to be called when the specific conditions I've setup in ExecutionState, exists, i.e. in 1 class, which won't be the event sender class (by design).

I know it's probably been answered many times in the past. Is it a case of doing mechanically, perhaps setting a flag in the event parameters to define it as coming from it's own class, or is their a more elegant way of doing it.

Thanks.
Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the signature of the vanilla [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) class, the first parameter is `object sender`. This is a typical pattern in the .NET framework, and it allows you to compare for equality with the object which raised the event:

```
public EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(this.Equals(sender))
   {
       //...
   }
}
```

Following this idiom would be well understood by developers using your API, and as such makes sense to follow, IMO.

Comment: Of course. I shouldn't create these questions so late in the night, when my brain is fried. I've been using object sender in event handlers since Delphi 2.0 in 97.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the events in say, ASP.NET, you'll find pretty much all of the handlers have a signature like this:

```
public delegate EventHandler(object _sender, EventArgs _args);
```

Where, of course, `EventArgs` is some `EventArgs`-derived class.  `_sender` always refers to whatever object is raising the event.

You could implement something similar, either in the delegate-signature as outlined above, or in a custom `EventArgs`-esque class, the abstract base of which might look something like this:

```
public abstract class MyEventArgs
{
    private object m_Sender = null;

    public MyEventArgs(object _sender)
    {
        m_Sender = _sender;
    } // eo ctor

    public object Sender { get { return m_Sender; } }
} // eo class MyEventArgs
```

Ensuring of course that all your event-objects derive from this:

```
public class SomeEventArgs : MyEventArgs { /* ... */ }
```

You would then raise your events thusly:

```
if(OnMyEvent != null)
    OnMyEvent(new SomeEventArgs(this));
```

Recipients can then do a comparison to see if it was, indeed, them who sent it.